# Gitlab Pages 401

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I’ve added my custom domain to gitlab pages with no issues, now I want to also add the www. subdomain but it keeps failing to verify. If you try to load the url gives 401.

The txt record is there for the www subdomain is there and I’ve waited a while for it to propagate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Visibility, project features, permissions" in GitLab (Project > Settings > General).

Look for the "Pages" section:
"With GitLab Pages you can host your static websites on GitLab"

See link here to GitLab forum:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/401-error-when-adding-custom-domain-to-gitlab-pages/30517/2

Comment: That's not it. It is set to everyone

Comment: @Vale this was a suggestion as _one_ of the things that you have to set. I'm not suggesting it will solve your exact issue.

Comment: I know, but that's the reason I did not accept it. (I'm not the one who downvoted it btw)

Comment: Understood @vale but responses to questions are there to help others that may be facing this configuration issue. I appreciate that you may not have been the one to downvote it. Did you solve the issue in the end?

Comment: It solved on its own for a month (I did not change anything), but later went back to 401 so I switched the site off Gitlab for the moment...

Comment: I had a similar issue, I resolved it by removing the domain and repo and rebuilding it, it seems people may have intermittent issues?